# get compsci.stackexchange.com site to redirect here

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Since the name of the site is "Computational Science", I frequently type in [compsci.stackexchange.com](http://compsci.stackexchange.com) instead of [scicomp.stackexchange.com](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), and I suspect this is a common error.

I suggest the [former](http://compsci.stackexchange.com) be redirected to the [latter](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 10):

We spent... *Waaaay* too much time discussing this internally.

[As Mrozek notes](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242/get-compsci-stackexchange-com-site-to-redirect-here/243#243), compsci is *also* a common abbreviation for Computer Science. A site for which can be found at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ - note that we intentionally avoided using the abbreviation for *either* site, because no matter which one we pick, we'll end up directing some people to the wrong site.

My preference would actually be to call this site "Scientific Computing" and thus keep the abbreviation in line with the name - but Computational Science with "scicomp" as the URL was a compromise solution.

If any change needs to be made though, I would suggest the name of the site rather than the subdomain.

Comment: +1 for Scientific Computing

Comment: @Shog9 - Do you happen to know if the solution I suggest in [my answer](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/314/149) to this question might be possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think that given the ambiguity between [Computational Science (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Science (https://cs.stackexchange.com/)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [Theoretical Computer Science (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) it is probably a good idea to reserve http://compsci.stackexchange.com/ so that it **isn't used by any stack exchange site**.

However, if it *is* going to be reserved, I would like to see that top level page list all three (or more sites in the future) which people might be looking for, with a brief description of the scope and purpose of each site to help them decide.

---

Incidentally, with regard to the [suggestion by Shog9♦](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/244/149) that we change the name of the site from ***Computational Science*** to ***Scientific Computing*** I would suggest that this is another question entirely.

See [my answer](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/310/149) on [What should the site name be?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/245/149) for more background on earlier discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I requested statistics on how many times [compsci.stackexchange.com](http://compsci.stackexchange.com/) page has been used. As of June 10, 2019, we are looking approximately at **1000 usages per year.**

Now, is 1000 usages per year a lot? I would say no, even if we assume that all of them want to get to [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Which is certainly not true, since a decent amount of them would want to go to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

So, the only possible resolution that I can see, is requesting a custom 404 Error page that would list three (?) aforementioned possible websites that the user might have meant.

With 1000 clicks a year, I would have a hard time justifying this development to StackExchange. And if only a third of that (optimistic estimate) were meant to go to our community, that would not likely make any difference for the growth of our community or, even, in the convenience of our existing community.

So, I tend to go for [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), unless the Community has a different perspective.

Comment: I think that listing the three sites is a good idea. Otherwise, [tag:status-declined] is OK.

Answer (score 1):

This alias actually existed when the site first launched. The problem is there's also a [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site, which arguably has a better claim to the name "compsci", so the alias got removed a few days into the public beta. I thought they were going to give it to the Computer Science site when it started, but possibly they're just leaving it undefined to avoid people accidentally going to one site when they meant the other

Comment: These two sites are going to need some REALLY different graphic design. I've already got confused and posted a question there that should have been here.